# Javascript model error handling advantages and disadvantages

Tags: javascript, validation, error-handling, logic

Before anyone thinks this is a duplicated of **Javascript error handling best practices**, I recommend you keep reading. If wondering, I'm working with `Google Closure`. It provides a fairly useful **MVC** architecture.

The thing is I have the chance to split the **business logic** from everything else in Javascript. This means a call to business logic only needs to handle *data and validation*. On a faily complex site, primarily using single-page-application, this logic can grow as fat as you can imagine.

Obviously, business logic errors need to be handled and shown to the user in an user-friendly way. This can be done by the controller and the view. My question resides in the connection between the business model and the controller. How should I return an error of some input in a validation, for example?

Imagine this: you have an input form with the amount of guests of a reservation and you intend to validate the sum is less than a given limit.

1. View: the user *inputs data*
2. Controller: via *events*, the change on data is detected
3. Controller: gather data and call something like `reservation.setGuests(adults, children)`
4. Model: *verify* (given internal info) if the sum of guests is valid (e.g. less than 3)
5. Model: **return SUCCESS or FAILURE with error message for user**
6. Controller: update the view with response of model

Please notice point number **5** where a result must be returned. The only two ways I can think of returning this kind of result is:

1. Throwing an **exception** in case something goes wrong with the validation. Return nothing.
2. Always return a **Result object** which knows the result of the operation and has additional info like the error message or the data needed by the controller.

These two solutions (I can think of) have the following advantages/disadvantages:

Exception:

- Pro: clean code inside the model
- Con: try-catch is really slow

Result:

- Pro: fastest option
- Con: every result involves an object
- Con: verify each result before continuing on next business instruction (ugly^ugly)

**Now, what is best for error handling in the model? Exception or Result object? Are there any better options?**

Comment: i don't believe that try/catch will be any slower from a user perspective. in V8, if you call out from a try/catch, that function executes at normal speed. even if it turned 5ms into 15ms, who cares about 10ms? go with the flow, not premature performance optimizations. if the only con is "really slow" and really slow is negligible, it's obvious. not enough coders throw anyway, which is sad.

Comment: I just started developing using the Exception model. I forgot to tell you I already use the `closure compiler` which does a lot of optimizations. Thank you @dandavis. On the long run I think I'll return here to answer my own question.